# Akka HTTP Json Marshalling

Tags: json, mongodb, marshalling, akka-http, spray-json

I'm building simple REST API using Akka-HTTP and MongoDB for persistence. For Marshalling and Unmarshalling HTTP requests I'm using spray json. Following [MongoDB documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.1/getting-started/quick-tour-case-classes/) I defined entities like that:

```
package entities

import org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId

case class Person(
  _id: ObjectId,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  emailConfirmed: Boolean,
  telephone: String,
  ...
)

object Person {

  def apply(
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    telephone: String,
    ...
  ): Publisher = new Publisher(
    new ObjectId(),
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    false,
    telephone,
    ...
  )
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to write a lot of boilerplate code to enable Marshalling-Unmarshalling:

```
implicit object PublisherItemFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Publisher] {
  def write(publisher: Publisher) = JsObject(
    "_id" -> JsString(publisher._id.toString),
    "firstName" -> JsString(publisher.firstName),
    "lastName" -> JsString(publisher.lastName),
    "email" -> JsString(publisher.email),
    "telephone" -> JsString(publisher.telephone),
    ...
  )

  def read(json: JsValue) = {
    val jsObject = json.asJsObject
    jsObject.getFields(
      "_id",
      "firstName",
      "lastName",
      "email",
      "telephone",
      ...
    ) match {
      case Seq(
        _id,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        telephone,
        ...
      ) ⇒ Publisher(
        firstName.convertTo[String],
        lastName.convertTo[String],
        email.convertTo[String],
        telephone.convertTo[String],
        ...
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I have approx 10 different entities that have to be saved in the Mongo, and each of them have 5-15 fields. With this number of entities, this kind of approach will produce too much boilerplate.
What could be a better way of doing it, with less boilerplate ? May-be there is another Json-serialization library instead of "spray-json" which can figure things out automatically with less code ?

Or how can I define Marshalling class for `org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId` using Spray-Json ? This will also help to get rid of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

Use automatic derivation:

```
  object EntitesJsonProtocol extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val placeResponseFormat = jsonFormat19(Person.apply)
    def personToJson(p: Person) = p.toJson
  }
```

the `personToJson` method is implemented so you don't have to contaminate your code with json imports, note that the order of declaration is important if a person is embedded inside a publisher you will have to declare `personFormat` before `publisherFormat`